# How to fix partition table after resizing bootcamp, MacOS disappear

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have an issue accessing my MacOS data, can someone guide me how to fix this?
I tried to increase the BOOTCAMP using MiniTool Partition Wizard.
After that both MacOS and Bootcamp Windows disappear from the boot menu (Power on then press Option).
Now I have to use a temporary MacOS on my extend SSD. But still can't access the data from the main MacOS.
Do you have any idea on how to fix this, if I can use my MacOS and Windows as before that is great, but in case it is difficult at least can I access to MacOS disk to just copy some important data?
I saw some post to fix this by adjusting the "hex" but I don't quite understand that, and it seems suitable for different case depending on different partition table, therefore I can't just apply blindly as my partition table is different with others.
Below is my "diskutil list":

- 300GB which is my main MacOS (I need to access its data)
- 69.4 GB is my Bootcamp Windows
- 100 GB storage disk of my Mac data (the only one I can access now)
- The rest are there by the system.

Please assist to guide me how to fix this if you know. Appreciate.
Thank you.

To add info on what I did when resizing the Bootcamp:

- I use MacOS Disk Utility to resize the disk0s1 down, to have free space (10GB)
- Then I boot to Bootcamp Windows, using the MiniTool Partition Wizard with the feature "Extend Partition" to extend my Bootcamp (10GB)

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you any save of this system? You can try : `diskutil repairdisk disk0` but I've a doubt on the solution.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, 
Thank you for your comment, and you give me some hope. I updated the question by adding what I did with Mini Tool Wizard, also I added the output of the hexdump as your suggestion. I hope that helps. Sorry for the late reply due to the different timezone from my country.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Jean_JD, ya I tried the repair disk but unfortunate it doesn't solve my issue.
Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo get -r show disk0` command shows values stored in the GUID Partition Table (GPT) on the internal drive. `The sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=1 bs=128 | hexdump -Cv` shows values stored at the beginning of the second partition on the internal drive.

The size in blocks of a APFS container is stored in the 8 bytes at offset 40 (28 hexadecimal) of the partition. In your case the bytes are `fb 99 f2 04 00 00 00 00`. This can be converted to 512 byte sectors by the following steps.

1. Reverse the order and remove the leading zeros to get 4f299fb.
2. Use the Calculator application (or other equivalent means) to convert hexadecimal to decimal. In this case, the result is 83,007,995 blocks, where a block is 4096 bytes.
3. In your case, there are 8 sectors per block. So the conversation to sectors is accomplished by multiplying by 8 to get 664,063,960 sectors, which is 340,000,747,520 bytes.

However, the output from the `sudo gpt -r show disk0` command shows the size of the partition, with this APFS container, is only be 644,531,248 sectors, which is 329,999,998,976 bytes. This discrepancy would prevent any volumes in the APFS container from mounting.

Apparently, the macOS APFS container in the second partition and Windows NTFS volume in the third partition overlap by 10 GB. Since you can not mount the Windows NTFS volume, there is not enough information posted to the question to know this for certain. In other words, location and size of the NTFS volume is currently unknown. Also, neither the APFS container or NTFS volume may be intact.

I suppose, since the data on the macOS APFS volumes is important, the following commands could be used to remove the Windows partition and expand APFS partition to 340 GB. Hopefully, the desired volumes will mount and the data can be recovered.

```
diskutil unmount disk0s3
sudo gpt -f remove -i 3 disk0
sudo gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0
sudo gpt -f add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 664063960 -t apfs disk0
```

Comment: Yes David, 10GB is the amount that I tried to move from MacOS to the Windows Bootcamp (used Disk Utility to decrease MacOS down 10 GB, used MiniTool Partition Wizard to increase Windows bootcamp more 10GB.
In fact, after I have done so, the Windows still can be boot and working as usual (but the size look weird, before it's ~2.5GB free out of 54GB, after increase it is ~2.5GB free out of 64GB)
Then after a restart, both Windows and MacOCS were gone

Comment: Unfortunately, what you did and what you posted differ. If you post the output from the command `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s3 count=1 bs=128 | hexdump -Cv`, I would have more information on the Windows partition.

Comment: Ya, I used the MiniTool, so don't really know what happened behind, maybe that's one of my fault. I tried the hexdump command on disks03 as your suggestion, it shows "dd: /dev/disk0s3: Resource busy" :(

Comment: You will need to enter `diskutil unmount disk0s3` before entering `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s3 count=1 bs=128 | hexdump -Cv`. However, if the resource was busy, then I already know what the output from `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s3 count=1 bs=128 | hexdump -Cv` will be.

Comment: Hi David, yes I tried again after unmount. I attach the output to the question too. I hope this help. Thank you very much for your kind and patient

Comment: Should I still try removing the bootcamp as your suggestion above?

Comment: Apparently, the last 10 GB of the  APFS partition containing macOS was overwritten by the NTFS (bootcamp) partition. Therefore, entering the commands given in my answer may or  may not result in mountable APFS volumes. Even if a volume mounts, there may be corruption within the volume. So, if you enter the commands in my answer and problems occur, then there is very little I can offer to help.

Comment: I see. But that is the only hope right? If no other solutions, I will have to try that one then, as I don’t have any others idea anyway.

Comment: Hi David, hope you are doing well, I left the macbook that has issue since last time we talked to use a temporary one. Now I go back to give it the last try, I tried the command as your suggestion, but the “sudo gpt -f remove -i 3 disk0” return an error “sudo: command not found”, I tried remove the sudo part, them it says “gpt: illegal option — f”. 
Do you have any comment? Thank you.

Comment: Your question shows the use of the `gpt` and `gdisk` commands. Where were you booted from when you entered these commands. An internal or external drive? An installer, macOS, Recover or Internet Recovery? What product version does the output from `sw_vers` show?

Comment: Hi David, sorry please just ignore my previous question. I managed to run the commands you suggested from the answer. And wowwww problem is resolved perfectly. My original MacOS has been recovered and works perfectly now. I actually had no hope and prepare for the fact that I will lost all the data. But you saved me. I really appreciate your kind and patient. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is still the possibility that the partition has corruption. I would consider backing up your important data, reformat the partition (erase the partition) and reinstall macOS.